# Pop ups on installs not always happening Macbook M1 13.0.1

Tags: macos, security, install, apple-silicon

I have been having a problem with software installs where the popup does not happen to prompt the next action since I moved to my Macbook M1. I also have a Mac Mini that I was having the same problem (Mainly with Adobe Products)

I was able to get all my Adobe Products to install on my M1 Mac Mini, but now I am having issues with my Macbook. (13.0.1)

I am wondering if there is a security setting that prevents popups on the desktop when installing apps.

Attaching an image of what I see when I am trying to install the Creative Cloud installer.

[image]

Comment: It would be helpful to provide some/a screenshot(s).

Comment: Would it also be possible to include a screenshot of the popup? Is there an error showing up?

Comment: @Thinkr I am not getting any popup, it just goes idle

Comment: Ah ok.ㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤ

Comment: First thing to do would be update from 13.0.1, which was as buggy as all heck.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "the popup". The one piece of info you've given shows that the installer is not responding, i.e. the process is 'stuck'. That's not normal. But for a problem with Adobe software, I would get support directly from them. That's why you pay them the big bucks.

Comment: @benwiggy Adobe determined it was a problem with permissions,  I added a new user and installed the software and now I am able to use the Adobe Products

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a work around for this issue, I added a new user, installed Creative Cloud, and then removed the user. It solved my issue.

I am assuming since I have been migrating my version of my MacOS from Machine to Machine for the last ten years that there is a permission issue with the Adobe files.

Comment: Out of curiosity…are you migrating from Intel to Apple Silicon?